# Bought an HP Probook from a reseller, seems to have wrong graphics card

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, motherboard

I have bought a Probook from Ebay, 'opened, never used', however despite being a Probook 450 G9 with an i5 processor, has the UHD graphics card. The listing suggested it should come with the Iris Xe, and the HP website suggests the i3 models come with the UHD, the i78 and i9 models with the Xe. The graphics as I understand is integral to the motherboard, so how do I have an i5 version with the UHD graphics installed?

Are people putting i5 processors on i3 motherboards for cheap resale?

Comment: Modern iGPUs are actually built into the CPU itself.

Comment: Good point. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

The
[10th Generation Intel Core i5 Processors](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/series/195732/10th-generation-intel-core-i5-processors.html)
all contain the UHD component as part of the CPU
(except for the F and KF performance series).

The UHD component is not a separate graphics card, so it's
always present.

As regarding the
[HP ProBook 450 15.6 inch G9 Notebook PC (6A190EA)](https://www.hp.com/emea_africa-en/products/laptops/product-details/product-specifications/2101279337)
(if that's your model),
it is indeed specified as including Intel Iris Xᵉ Graphics.

You might be missing a driver, in order for the card to be
recognized, so try installing the
[Intel driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/785597/intel-arc-iris-xe-graphics-windows.html),
dating from January 2024.

Comment: you're prolific here! I am seeing something that suggests my problem might be solved later today. I believe it has shipped with 1x8 GB RAM, whereas https://www.hp.com/au-en/shop/hp-probook-450-15-6-inch-g9-notebook-pc-6g8y7pa.html#:~:text=HP%20ProBook%20450%2015.6-inch%20G9%20Laptop%201%2012th,GB%29%207%20Weighs%201.74%20kg%20%28See%20more%20Specifications%29 suggests the Iris Xe requires dual channel, which I've got on order for delivery today.